# On-site waste-sorting robot feasibility and availability

Tags: computer-vision, industrial-robot

I am thinking about a project at my university for doing on-site waste sorting. The problem with having one waste bin for recyclables, compost and landfill and doing the sorting at a facility, is that the organic materials can destroy paper and other recyclable materials.

I have searched quite a bit but all of the robotic solutions available that I have found are for facilities. I am looking for a robotic bin to be deployed in replacement of the traditional waste and recycling bin.

The budget is approximately $1000.

- $1000 -- is that materials cost only, or does it include assembly and
  maintenance costs?: materials and assembly not maintenance for all 4 bins plus robotic sorter
- it must be bin-sized (whatever that means): let's say 3 ft (height) x
  2 ft (length) x 2 ft (width) per bin and there are 4 bins -- recycle
  paper, recycle plastic, compost, landfill
- Do you have weight requirements so the consumer can move the bin to
  the curb, or are you planning to have the robot separate the
  materials into other, mobile, bins?: There are no weight
  requirements. We should be able to use a forklift to move it. What
  would be nice is to have a single waste entry hole which customers
  use. The device should internally sort the waste into the 4 bins
  listed above. The entry hole and sorter should be 1 ft (height) x 8
  ft (length) x 2 ft (width) to fit directly on top of the set of 4
  adjacent bins.
- What power is available?: It can be plugged into a wall outlet (in
  case there is one nearby) but should also be able to use a
  rechargeable battery (in case there isn't).
- What about environmental concerns, especially if this is to be
  located outside? Don't forget noise constraints and safety concerns.:
  The whole point of this is to reduce waste and help the environment.
  Assume the noise it can make can be as loud as a heater, AC unit, or
  fan. The entire system should be one box with one waste entry hole --
  the rest should be blackbox-ed, so it should be safe.
- And, most importantly, what characteristics of the materials are you
  planning to use for doing the actual sorting?: the shorter should be
  able to detect pure recyclable plastic vs recyclable paper vs
  organic/food material vs pure waste using either computer vision or
  chemical techniques or both.
- What size requirements are there for the products themselves?: The
  waste whole should be .75 ft x .75 ft so assume the waste is less
  than .75 ft^3
- For example, how to detect organic garbage from non-organic (and do
  it many times a day without human intervention to "resupply
  chemicals") can be a topic of research that could take a couple of
  years itself: Yes this is a good point. However, my question is more
  focused on whether it's possible to use the robots already
  commercially available today to solve this problem.

I read through [how to ask](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) but so here is my specific question: Is there a commercially available robot today that does or can be retro-fitted to do this on-site waste sorting?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Govinda Dasu, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: I'm going to edit it as I mentioned below

Comment: I will need a bit more time, as I'm requesting the answers to the questions.

Comment: Hi guys, maybe I should rephrase my question as: Are there any existing robotic solutions to this problem or can some existing robot be programmed to do this job? I'm pretty sure we don't have the resources to build our own robot from scratch-- maybe we might have resources to program one. Let me know if this rephrasing would still allow my question to be valid on this site.

Comment: If you re-worded your question as you describe, it still sounds to me as if the answers would be mostly opinion-based.  You would end up with a lot of "it depends," which isn't really the type of question-and-answer this site is looking for.  As @MarkBooth mentions in another comment, the How to Ask and tour links might help you with the types of questions that folks at this site can help with.

Comment: I'll go through that in more detail and propose another rephrase

Comment: Sorry the last week was busy. I'll try to do this rephrasing this week as it's Thanksgiving break.

Comment: I have edited the answer based on the feedback.

Comment: I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: In other words, you would still be better off asking a variant of "This is my problem. How do I solve it?" rather than "This is my problem. What should I buy?".

Answer (score 1):

A robotics student would attach a manipulator on the bin and see what they can get done.   A good roboticist wouldn't even consider whether or not robotics was a good solution until the problem's requirements were well-defined.   You kind of have two requirements already:  the cost must be less than $300 (is that materials cost only, or does it include assembly and maintenance costs?), and it must be bin-sized (whatever that means).   Do you have weight requirements so the consumer can move the bin to the curb, or are you planning to have the robot separate the materials into other, mobile, bins?   What power is available?   What about environmental concerns, especially if this is to be located outside?   Don't forget noise constraints and safety concerns.  And, most importantly, what characteristics of the materials are you planning to use for doing the actual sorting?  What size requirements are there for the products themselves?   You need to be able to sense the characteristics, manage the span of sizes and shapes, and maneuver the materials to their destinations.

In summary, start by defining the problem and the design constraints before you decide that robotics is the solution.

Comment: I will edit my answer soon to answer these questions.

Comment: I have edited the answer based on the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of unknowns to this problem, as SteveO has mentioned in an answer. My suggestion is to start inventing missing functionalities one by one and leave the assembly into a complete product for when all that is done. For example, how to detect organic garbage from non-organic (and do it many times a day without human intervention to "resupply chemicals") can be a topic of research that could take a couple of years itself.

Doing this, you can focus on solving the core of each problem (detecting a specific kind of garbage, or handling variable-sized and variable-consistency objects) without bothering with complexities of other problems. When you have each problem solved, you can start piecing things together and make a product.

Comment: I have edited the answer based on the feedback.